# mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show fields from `': Got error 28 from storage engine (1030)

Tags: mysql

I transferred over my mysql database from one hard drive partition to another after the original partition was apparently full. Afterwards, I modified the my.cnf file so that the data directory points to the new partition. This new partition does indeed have extra space, but when I try to dump the mysql database, or even show the columns of a table, I'm left with the following error:

```
Got error 28 from storage engine (1030)
```

My df -h command gives the following:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/isw_jiajcifaa_SecureDatap1 880G  873G     0 100% /
tmpfs                  12G     0   12G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   12G  236K   12G   1% /dev
tmpfs                  12G  140K   12G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sdc1             917G  257G  615G  30% /data
```

I moved the files from the original /var/lib/mysql to /data/mysql and changed the my.cnf as follows:

```
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /data/mysql/mysqld.pid    
socket          = /data/mysql/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /data/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
```

Does anyone have an idea of the error?

Comment: The error means that there is not enough disk space. What size is the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem wasn't the location of the database, which I moved to the correct partition, but rather the sockets that MYSQL uses to transfer the data. The sockets are defined in both the my.cnf and debian.cnf (for Ubuntu), and since the partition was full, absolutely no data could be read from MYSQL. I also had to change the temporary directory initiative in my.cnf.